# Presenting a view controller in Universal app, iOS 4 to 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

Is there a shorter way to present a view controller, when wanting to support iOS 4 and above (for the iPhone 3G) in a universal app?

Currently I have this below, but I dislike how I need a UIPopoverController property, which I need especially because if the view controller is say for picking an image, when an image is picked the popover needs to be dismissed.

```
@interface SASuccessViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *myPopoverController;
@end

@implementation SASuccessViewController
-(void)showViewController:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]) {
            [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];//iOS 5 and above
        } else {
            [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO]; //iOS 4, deprecated in iOS 6
        }
    } else {
        if (!self.myPopoverController) {
            self.myPopoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController] autorelease];
        } else {
            [self.myPopoverController setContentViewController:viewController];
        }
        [self.myPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
    [viewController release];
}
-(void)dealloc {
    [_popoverController release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Considering that when iOS 4 was the latest (and not a Universal app), the method would be just:

```
-(void)showViewController:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];
    [viewController release];
}
```

What I have now seem quite bloated. Is there a better way of showing a view controller on Universal apps (let alone supporting iOS 4)?

Comment: If you don't want a popover controller, just use a standard modal presentation? `presentModalViewController/presentViewController`?

Comment: I do want a popover, on the iPad presenting a modal view controller for a small (iphone sized view) doesn't look good.

Comment: Did you check modalPresentationStyle as a property of VCs available starting at iOS 3.2 for iPad -> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalPresentationStyle

Comment: @user387184, yes but the view is about 320x320 in size, it really looks stupid if presented modally on an iPad, even as a "page".

Comment: IMHO, this isn't very ugly... Your only concern should be whether you are calling this code multiple time, and if so, I'd suggest you just #define a macro and get on with it. The macro arguments would be the popoverController, the viewController and possibly the sender.

Comment: If you want it a little shorter, you can always enable ARC. Saves a release call and the whole dealloc method... And with lazy instantiation you wouldn't have to check if `myPopoverController` is already alloc/init'ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a much better way to present modal view in a universal app. The logic you have is all pretty much necessary. Here are some tips, though:

1. Considering that you are not specifying a completion block, it is probably okay to stick with the deprecated `presentViewController:animated:` method until you remove support for iOS 4.0. In other words, you could just do this:

   ```
   if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
       [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];        
   }
   ```
2. Or, as someone else stated, you could create a UIViewController category for the presentModalViewController methods. At least this will clean up your UIViewController a bit.
3. If your SASuccessViewController inherits directly from UIViewController, you might consider creating another UIViewController for SASuccessViewController to inherit from. For example, MasterViewController could be a view controller that any of your view controller's could inherit from. The idea here is to clean up your view controllers by moving the code to your super class, and at the same time eliminate repetition of code when presenting modal controllers in different view controllers.

   ```
   @interface MasterViewController ()
   @property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
   - (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController origin:(id)origin;
   @end

   @implementation MasterViewController
   @synthesize popoverController;

   - (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController origin:(id)origin {
       if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
           if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]) {
               [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];//iOS 5 and above
           } else {
               [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO]; //iOS 4, deprecated in iOS 6
           }
       } else {
           if (!self.popoverController) {
               self.popoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController] autorelease];
           } else {
               [self.popoverController setContentViewController:viewController];
           }

           if(![self.popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
               if([origin isKindOfClass:[UIBarButtonItem class]]) {
                   [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:origin
                                                  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
               } else {
                   [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectZero inView:origin permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
               }
           }
       }
   }

   @end
   ```

And then you could just do this from your `SASuccessViewController`:

```
-(void)showViewController:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self presentViewController:x origin:sender];
}
```

Comment: However how would I handle popoverController property, as far as I if you have multiple views to present in popovers, you need multiple popovercontrollers, you can't just reuse the same one?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to display multiple popovers at the same time?

Comment: @Micheal, no but if I different views to show in popovers in different places at different times, should I reuse one property?

Comment: Yeah you can reuse one property, as long as only one UIPopoverController is visible at a time. If you use a strong property, everytime you create a new object w/ that property the old object is automatically released.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a category on UIViewController to do this:

```
@implementation UIViewController (PresentViewController)

- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion;

@end

@interface UIViewController (PresentViewController)

- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion {
    if([super respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]){
        [super presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:flag completion:completion];
    } else {
        [super presentModalViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:flag];
    }
}
```

Comment: The completion block would never be called if the "else" case is triggered, which makes the method misleading.

Comment: Agreed, however based on his code, he's not using the completion block.

Comment: This still requires the popover code to be done separately, so not entirely the answer I'm looking for, but thanks.

Comment: Yeah, there really isn't a great way to simply it without making the source code tough to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a instance of your `UIViewController` and set the modal presentation style to `UIModalPresentationStyle` to formsheet or to currentContext if you want it in a popover and give animation using `transitionStyle` and then finally present it.
I hope this will solve your problem.

```
        UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        [viewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
        [viewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];            
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

so in case it doesnot work with ios4 we can use directly presentasmodalview controller

Comment: The issue with this is that it is only supports iOS 5.0+